# SpriteKit add one node's children to another

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my sprite kit project I have a scene .sks file which contains the ground physicsBody and background graphics. The scene will be loaded from this file. It also contains an empty node called container. I have another .sks file for each level which contain blocks and enemies. When my scene is initialised I load a level from one of my level .sks files (casting the SKScene to an SKNode) and add into the empty "container" node. I use this code:

```
import SpriteKit

extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(SKNode.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as SKNode
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.childNodeWithName("//container")?.addChild(SKNode.unarchiveFromFile("level1")!)
    }

    override class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

However this means that there is an empty unused node in the node hierarchy:

```
Scene
-background
-ground
-container
--level scene(cast to SKNode) <- empty node here
---block
---enemy
```

so my question is: how do I add one node's children to another?
-I cannot directly set the children property (not assignable)
-I cannot replace the container node as I loose all its properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the `children` array - you'll need to cast from `AnyObject` back to `SKNode` to add the node to the new parent:

```
for node in oldParentNode.children {
    node.removeFromParent()
    newParentNode.addChild(node as AnyObject)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (untested), just add them one by one:

```
for (CCNode* node in [oneNode.children copy]) 
{
    [node removeFromParent]; 
    [anotherNode addChild:node];
}
```

The copy is needed to avoid mutating the children array while enumerating it. Alternatively you could also use the reverseObjectEnumerator. Removing the node must be done so addChild: won't complain about the node already having a parent.

Comment: Thanks-it should be easy to port to swift, and sprite kit is very similar in some parts to cocos2d